# using reChart in quantmod

Tags: r, charts, quantmod

I am trying to use the reChart tool in quantmod to zoom into my chart, following the example from here:
http://www.quantmod.com/documentation/chartSeries.html

however, when I try to zoom back out to the original chart, it doesn't work. Is there an example that could show how to zoom back out to the original chart

Comment: There are no examples of the use of reChart at the link you offered. You probably need to show the code that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `subset=""`

Also, see `?zoomChart`

```
> library(quantmod)
> getSymbols("SPY", src='yahoo', from='2011-01-01', to='2012-01-01')
[1] "SPY"
> chartSeries(SPY)
> zoomChart("last 1 week") # zoom in
> reChart(subset="") # zoom out

> zoomChart("last 2 months") # zoom in
> zoomChart() # zoom out
```

Comment: did so, and I have a follow-up question. I have used a simple moving average rule to create Buy and Sell signals. Now, I want to show them on this chart just as simple 'B','S' labels at all the different price points where it generates a signal. Is that possible and if so, is there an example I can follow.

Comment: maybe something like `addTA(Cl(SPY[findValleys(Cl(SPY))]), pch="B", type="p", col='blue', on=1)`

Comment: this is fine, but it shows several B signals in places where I wouldn't necessarily Buy, so I want to pick and chose which ones to label....is that possible, or would I need to write a customized equivalent of findValleys

Comment: make an xts with your buy prices, replace  `Cl(SPY[findValleys(Cl(SPY))])` with your xts object.